# How to modify a method from category which is added using cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I have added AFNetworking using cocoapods and I need to modify UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.m category, and more specific I need to add a custom logging statement used in my project to the end of dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 70000
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:AFNetworkingTaskDidCompleteNotification object:nil];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:AFNetworkingTaskDidResumeNotification object:nil];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:AFNetworkingTaskDidSuspendNotification object:nil];
#endif

    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification object:nil];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification object:nil];
}
```

Is it possible to swizzle/subclass/modify/etc this dealloc method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop using it via cocoapods and instead *fork* your own version of the AFNetworking repo on github and use that instead.

In this way you have the opportunity to give any improvements you make back to the community.